# Nested JSON object - object notation response is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I hope someone can assist.

I have the following example of a JSON object which I save to my mongoDB via mongoose:

```
{"@context":"https://w3id.org/chainpoint/v2",
"type":"ChainpointSHA256v2",
"targetHash":"5eaad1259897efd03dc8ea30d1a0d717fec7ec23b6b1487ad689353a240d92a6",
    "merkleRoot":"6d6fd23027665e754b2af5fe351bd7096e13ad5706402d24c26afe8db88f95c7",
        "proof":[{"right":"6a7a3efc12b60355bedcd82d2045f56589bca7090125a100128c70ff79031fc7"}],
        "anchors":[{"type":"BTCOpReturn",
    "sourceId":"6452eae85d1450b0b1f1104c07d105991a32f0a7c44a449268ceaebf6599566f"}]}
```

I have setup my "Anchor" model in Mongoose to save this as an Object.

In my code, The Object is indeed an Object, when I check the type.

When I do the following in code, the value is successfully printed (where the mongoose model is "Anchor"), and "anchor.receipt" is the exact content as printed in the code snippet above:

```
console.log('***Receipt for ID: ' + anchor.receipt);
```

The PROBLEM comes in when I try and do the following. The result for both the below is "undefined":

```
console.log('***targetHash for ID: ' + anchor.receipt.targetHash);
console.log('***MerkleRoot for ID: ' + anchor.receipt.merkleRoot);
```

I am also trying to get the following working, but it gives an error, saying the "0" is not defined:

```
console.log('***SourceId for ID: ' + anchor.receipt.anchors[0].sourceId);
```

SO, as you can see :), I am having issues retrieving the values in the nested JSON object. ANY help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Solved:

JSON.parse was the answer. Hopefully this can help someone else in future.

```
var data3 = JSON.parse(anchor.receipt);
console.log('***SourceId for ID: ' + data3.anchors[0].sourceId);
```